# How to get OR(||) and AND (&&) statements to work together? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I can't get this code to work

```
if ($title != 'Main' || $nSpace == 56 || $nSpace == 30 && $ifHome != 361)
```

So i settled for this code

```
if ($title != 'ArticleCategories' || $nSpace == 1)
    if ($nSpace == 0 && $ifHome != 1)
```

So, i am now wondering how can i get those two lines into one line in the way so that it works? I know how to get multiple or || statements into one line but not the or || and and && statements together.

Comment: +1.  I cannot imagine a more delicious madness.  "I cannot get my unplugged vacuum cleaner to work, so I settled for a flashlight plugged into a garden hose."   I especially liked the code to handle the ($nSpace == 1 && $nSpace == 0) scenario.  Tee hee hee...

Comment: Don't forget to accept Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parens to group the logic together in a manner that makes sense for your program.

```
if ($title != 'Main' || $nSpace == 56 || ($nSpace == 30 && $ifHome != 361))
```

Comment: So then group the logic together in a manner that makes sense for your program.

Comment: @user585303, based on your second example, the code would be `if ($title != 'ArticleCategories' || $nSpace == 1) && ($nSpace == 0 && $ifHome != 1)) ...` but Ignacio's answer is still correct - use parentheses so you don't have to concern yourself with precedence rules.